# Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StartDate not found

Tags: tfs

I have some iterations in TFS project where I am trying to read the start and end date based on:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudiouk/archive/2013/01/16/migrating-tfs2010-sprint-dates-to-tfs2012-iteration-path-based-dates.aspx

I have manually set the start and end date

[image]

I do:

```
       string WIQL = string.Format("SELECT * FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = '{0}'", projectName);

        WorkItemCollection wic = wit.Query(WIQL);

        foreach (WorkItem wi in wic)
        {

            try
            {
                DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime(wi.Fields["Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StartDate"].Value);
                Console.WriteLine("Item does have start date!" + wi.IterationId);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Item does not have start date!" + wi.IterationId);
            }

        }

        Console.WriteLine("Done");

    }
```

But an exception is thrown for all items meaning that the Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StartDate field is never found. I am using TFS API 11 and 12.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Iteration dates are not stored in work item fields, they are global for the team project. The right way to get iteration dates is by using CommonStructureService:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("<collection url>"));
ICommonStructureService4 css = tfs.GetService<ICommonStructureService4>();

NodeInfo ni = css.GetNodeFromPath(@"\<project name>\Iteration\<iteration name>");
Console.WriteLine("Start date: {0}", ni.StartDate);
Console.WriteLine("Emd date: {0}", ni.FinishDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a close look at the work item type.  You can download the [TFS Power tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f) and then export any work item type to xml.  This will allow you to explore exactly what type each field is.  Perhaps the "Start Date" you're looking for is actually a different type in your TFS instance.

The code in your question looks ok.  I tested it by creating a User Story in my TFS instance, and setting it to Active.  This set the start date on the story which was found by your code.